# move comments to chat rephrase

Tags: discussion

Would you consider rephrasing this action? The word "move" makes me think that if I click it, the comments will be removed from the question/answear. But in fact the comments are just copied.

Comment: Where does it say that?  The only time I recall seeing anything close to this is "Please avoid extended discussions in comments.  Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" - Which doesn't quite say the same.

Comment: Ok, you remember it better than me. I am not native speaker, to me it sounds like the comments (that consists the discussion) would be moved to chat.

Comment: I could see how it could be interpret it either way, but I have always read it as "would you like to move the active discussion to chat", not moving the comments themselves.

Comment: And this is the problem, that you can read it both ways which means that part of users will rather not use this feature. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97664/if-you-move-to-chat-do-your-comments-get-deleted?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

Personally I have never had an issue with the phrasing. It seems direct and accurate. I have used it before. However, if it is confusing people who speak English as a second language, perhaps it could be a little more explicit with what happens

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to create a chat room to continue this discussion?

Comment: Like you, I don't see a problem with the current phrasing, but the rephrasing certainly removes the ambiguity

Comment: Do SO authors monitor this site?