# Reword "Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?” so it is clear what it does

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat, wording

My suggestion is to change

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

to

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to continue this discussion in chat?

When I have used this option for the first time, I was sure that comments will be removed from the post after *moving* them to the chat. And it appears that [I'm not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308597/what-happens-if-i-click-automatically-move-this-discussion-to-chat) the [only one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97664/if-you-move-to-chat-do-your-comments-get-deleted).